# Load a PWA on a local network as a homescreen app on Android

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I am making a simple progressive web app that lets me make requests to a server on my local network. I have a webserver on a domain `server-main.lan` and it uses a self signed certificate.

Everything works, but when I install it on my Android phone as an app (Add to Home screen), the address bar and the error message about the untrusted cert is always visible at the top. If I use `http` only, then whenever I have any input field (even one used for JS filtering only), a warning appears stating that the site is not secured and blah blah.

This "app" will never be distributed anywhere, its only usable on my local network. Is there a way to get rid of all the warnings and have it load nicely?

Comment: HTTPS is not an option if you want to install a functioning PWA. Without it, you can just install a shortcut to your website.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Figure out how to install the certificate on your phone.
2. Install a valid certificate on your web server; https://letsencrypt.org is free.

The advantage of the second option is it’ll work on every device.

Comment: Letsencrypt highly recommends not using them for this situation: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/ - so that leaves installing the cert on the phone. This works for sure, but isn't as seamless as I would like

Comment: Yes. Certificates for a host named localhost are nonsensical. Use a valid fully qualified domain name.

Comment: But I don't want to need to buy a domain. I specifically would like to use a localhost domain (or .lan domain). It seems silly that I would need to include a cert authority and buy a domain just to trust my own software

Comment: Domain names are cheap, but, if you don't want to do that, option 1 is your best bet.